# Unity Mavros client disconnects automatically

Tags: ros, rosbridge, mavros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ROSBridgeLib in Unity3D 2017.1 to connect to ROS on Ubuntu.

The turtlesim project works fine. I can control the turtle from Unity. I wrote a test subscriber to see talker messages ("/chatter") and it works fine as well.

When I tried connecting to mavros topics, for example "/mavros/global_position/compass_hdg", ROSBridge immediately disconnects the client. It says:

```
[INFO] [1505825883.664602]: [Client 21] Subscribed to /mavros/global_position/compass_hdg [INFO] [1505825883.910471]: Client disconnected. 0 clients total.
```

Here is my subscriber code:

```
using ROSBridgeLib;
using ROSBridgeLib.std_msgs;
using ROSBridgeLib.turtlesim;
using System.Collections;
using SimpleJSON;
using UnityEngine;

public class MavrosGlobalpositionCompassHdg : ROSBridgeSubscriber {

    public new static string GetMessageTopic() {
        return "/mavros/global_position/compass_hdg";
    }  

    public new static string GetMessageType() {
        return "std_msgs/Float64";
    }

    public new static ROSBridgeMsg ParseMessage(JSONNode msg) {
        return new Float64Msg(msg);
    }

    public new static void CallBack(ROSBridgeMsg msg) {
        Float64Msg hdg = (Float64Msg) msg;
        Debug.Log("MAVROS message: " + hdg.ToString());
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272384/unity-mavros-client-disconnects-automatically/) by [hermonir](https://answers.ros.org/users/31963/hermonir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2017-10-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fixed it.

The problem was in Float64Msg.cs in ROSBridgeLib.
Inside  Float64Msg(JSONNode msg), it tried parsing a json string as a double. Here is the fixed method:

```
public Float64Msg(JSONNode msg) {
    _data = double.Parse(msg["data"]);
}
```

---

Originally posted by [hermonir](https://answers.ros.org/users/31963/hermonir/) with karma: 26 on 2017-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-09**:
If you feel this is a problem with `ROSBridgeLib` it would be nice if you could report it to the authors, so they can include the fix in their sources.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-09**:
+1 for reporting back and telling us the solution btw.